# upload googlemap in android app, using eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm tring to upload googlemap in android app, using eclipse. But the results are that I only see white grid with no map on it. Is it because I used  a temporary Maps API Key? How can I register for a new Key?

Answer (score 0):

By upload googlemap, do you mean run an application that uses a mapactivity? If you've registered your key and put it in the xml correctly, you're almost certainly forgetting to add the INTERNET permission.

Comment: I meant to run an application that uses a mapactivity,i did add the INTERNET permission in mainfest: ... <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />. Regard the key registration, i put it in main.xml: ...<com.google.android.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/mapview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:clickable="true" android:apiKey="Nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxw"/></LinearLayout>. Thanks </manifest>